# CardView setCardBackgroundColor won't work

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I have made an adapter of **CardView** through the **RecyclerView** for me to use the same template of card for this feature of mine.

The objective is to **create certain cards with different colors**, based on the parameter `inc_status` in `INCCards.java`. But it doesn't just seem to work.

Here's the source code for the template card:

### ***item_inc_card.xml***

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/spacing_medium"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/spacing_medium"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/spacing_medium"
    android:background="@color/tertiary">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/spacing_none">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/spacing_large"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/spacing_large"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/spacing_large"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/spacing_medium"
                android:id="@+id/relative_layout">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/course_code"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_headline"
                    android:text="@string/course_code"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/course_title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/course_code"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_subhead"
                    android:text="@string/course_title" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/faculty"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/course_title"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:textStyle="italic"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_body"
                    android:text="@string/faculty" />


                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/status_icon"
                    android:src="@drawable/icon_avatar"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/size_user_icon"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/size_user_icon"
                    android:layout_above="@+id/faculty"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/inc_grade"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_body"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/status_icon"
                    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/status_icon"
                    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/status_icon"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/status_icon"
                    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/status_icon"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:text="@string/equiv_grade"/>

            </RelativeLayout>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0.001dp"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:id="@+id/line_divider"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/spacing_large"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/spacing_medium"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/spacing_medium"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_medium"
                android:id="@+id/semesterInfoLinearLayout">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/section"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_caption"
                    android:text="@string/section"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:layout_weight="0.33" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/semester"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_caption"
                    android:text="@string/semester"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:layout_weight="0.33"
                    android:gravity="center" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/acad_year"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_caption"
                    android:text="@string/acad_year"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:layout_weight=".33"
                    android:gravity="right" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>


    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

---

And for the fragment layout:

### ***item_inc_card.xml***

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_inc_cards"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/tertiary"/>
```

---

To where each card is initialized by the object

### ***INCCards.java***

```
package ph.edu.amitypipduo.myiit;

public class INCCards {
    String course_code, course_title, faculty, section, semester, acad_year;
    int inc_status, status_icon;
    final String inc_grade = "INC 3.00";

    public INCCards(String course_code, String course_title, String faculty, String section, String semester, String acad_year, String inc_status) {
        this.course_code = course_code;
        this.course_title = course_title;
        this.faculty = faculty;
        this.section = section;
        this.semester = semester;
        this. acad_year = acad_year;

        switch (inc_status) {
            case "notice":
                this.inc_status = R.color.inc_notice;
                this.status_icon = R.drawable.inc_notice;
                break;
            case "alert":
                this.inc_status = R.color.inc_alert;
                this.status_icon = R.drawable.inc_alert;
                break;
            case "warning":
                this.inc_status = R.color.inc_warning;
                this.status_icon = R.drawable.inc_warning;
                break;
            case "danger":
                this.inc_status = R.color.inc_danger;
                this.status_icon = R.drawable.inc_danger;
                break;
        }

    }

}
```

---

I tried setting the background color of the card at method `onBindViewHolder` by:

> `cardViewHolder.card_view.setCardBackgroundColor(inc_cards.get(i).inc_status);`

as seen here in

### ***INCAdapter.java***

```
package ph.edu.amitypipduo.myiit;

import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

public class INCAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<INCAdapter.CardViewHolder> {
    List<INCCards> inc_cards;

    public INCAdapter(List<INCCards> inc_cards){
        this.inc_cards = inc_cards;
    }

    @Override
    public CardViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_inc_card, viewGroup, false);
        CardViewHolder card_view_holder = new CardViewHolder(view);
        return card_view_holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(CardViewHolder cardViewHolder, int i) {
        cardViewHolder.course_code.setText(inc_cards.get(i).course_code);
        cardViewHolder.course_title.setText(inc_cards.get(i).course_title);
        cardViewHolder.faculty.setText(inc_cards.get(i).faculty);
        cardViewHolder.section.setText(inc_cards.get(i).section);
        cardViewHolder.semester.setText(inc_cards.get(i).semester);
        cardViewHolder.acad_year.setText(inc_cards.get(i).acad_year);
        cardViewHolder.inc_grade.setText(inc_cards.get(i).inc_grade);
        cardViewHolder.status_icon.setImageResource(inc_cards.get(i).status_icon);
        cardViewHolder.card_view.setCardBackgroundColor(inc_cards.get(i).inc_status);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return inc_cards.size();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }

    public static class CardViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        CardView card_view;
        TextView course_code, course_title, faculty, section, semester, acad_year, inc_grade;
        ImageView status_icon;


        CardViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            card_view = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_view);

            course_code = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.course_code);
            course_title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.course_title);
            faculty = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.faculty);
            inc_grade = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.inc_grade);
            section = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.section);
            semester = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.semester);
            acad_year = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.acad_year);

            status_icon = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.status_icon);
        }
    }
}
```

---

Then initializing the data in the fragment class and inflating the layout:

### ***INCMonitorFragment.java***

```
package ph.edu.amitypipduo.myiit;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class INCMonitorFragment extends Fragment {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    private RecyclerView recycler_view;
    private LinearLayoutManager linear_layout_manager;
    private INCAdapter inc_adapter;

    private List<INCCards> inc_cards;

    private void initializeData() {
        inc_cards = new ArrayList<>();
        inc_cards.add(new INCCards("CSC 198", "Methods of Research", "Prof. Cyrus Gabilla", "CS-1A", "SECOND SEMESTER", "AY 2014-2015", "danger"));
        inc_cards.add(new INCCards("POLSCI 2", "Philippine Govt. & Const.", "Prof. Cyrus Gabilla", "AB4", "SUMMER SEMESTER", "AY 2013-2014", "warning"));
        inc_cards.add(new INCCards("ENG 2N", "Writing in Discipline", "Prof. Rabindranath Polito", "B4", "FIRST SEMESTER", "AY 2012-2013", "alert"));
        inc_cards.add(new INCCards("MATH 51", "I Forgot the Course Title", "Prof. Forgotten Name", "69", "SECOND SEMESTER", "AY 2012-2013", "notice"));
    }


    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static INCMonitorFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        INCMonitorFragment fragment = new INCMonitorFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public INCMonitorFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }

        initializeData();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_inc_monitor, container, false);
        recycler_view = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_inc_cards);
        recycler_view.setHasFixedSize(true);

        linear_layout_manager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        recycler_view.setLayoutManager(linear_layout_manager);

        inc_adapter = new INCAdapter(inc_cards);
        recycler_view.setAdapter(inc_adapter);

        return view;
    }

    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }


}
```

---

But it only shows this:

[image]

Why does it not recognize the color? How come the `R.drawable.....` was recognized by the `onBindViewHolder` and not the `R.color.....`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Change

```
cardViewHolder.card_view.setCardBackgroundColor(inc_cards.get(i).inc_status);
```

to

```
int colorId = inc_cards.get(i).inc_status;
int color = cardViewHolder.card_view.getContext().getResources().getColor(colorId);
cardViewHolder.card_view.setCardBackgroundColor(color);
```

You are using the value from R.color instead of the value you set in your XML.

Comment: This! Thanks! No wonder it suggested `getResources().getColor()`, but the method is not recognized so I was wondering where to import it until I gave up. Thanks again. :)

Answer (score 10):

I'm getting a more reliable color overriding with this line:

```
setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(color));
```

instead of:

```
setCardBackgroundColor(color).
```

Comment: setCardBackgroundColor didn't do anything for me on com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView. setBackgroundTintList does the trick.

Answer (score 3):

One thing to add, make sure you have the alpha in your color number and if you don't just add `ff` at the begining of your color, otherwise it won't work correctly.

For example this works

`view.setCardBackgroundColor(0xff2ecc71)`

While this one shows a white background

`view.setCardBackgroundColor(0x2ecc71)`

Answer (score 0):

**Try to use Material Card View Instead**
then Do something LIke this:

```
private MaterialCardView imgIgnition;
imgIgnition = findViewById(R.id.imgIgnition);
imgIgnition.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#198754"));
```